# jsrender- access elements from complex structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsrender, jsviews

Im using JsRender Library for getting elements from a rest call as json
this is my Json structure:

```
{
   "bugs" : [
      {
         "component" : "Rx",
         "resolution" : "",
         "status" : "NEW",
         "summary" : "There is a big delay"
      },
      {
         "component" : "Rx",
         "resolution" : "",
         "status" : "NEW",
         "summary" : "problem"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to the access the status but I cannot, 
I have tried

```
{{:bugs.status}}
{{>~status}}
```

but none of these worked for me. 
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
{{for bugs}}
{{:status}}
</br>
    {{/for}}
```